# logging.handlers.BufferingHandler subclassed handler showing log twice

Tags: python, logging, standard-library

I am creating my own log handler by subclassing `BufferingHandler` present in [logging.handlers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html) module to add custom flushing strategies.

```
from logging.handlers import BufferingHandler
import logging

LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s'
logger = logging.getLogger('LogArchiver')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter(LOG_FORMAT)

class MyLogHandler(BufferingHandler):
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        logging.handlers.BufferingHandler.__init__(self, capacity)

    def flush(self):
        for record in self.buffer:
            print(self.format(record))
            #pass

    def shouldFlush(self, record):
        return False


h = MyLogHandler(1000)
h.setLevel(logging.INFO)
h.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(h)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(5):
        logger.info('test %s', i)
```

This is working well but showing log lines twice like BufferingHandler is flushing to console by default which I dont want. Its printing ..

```
root@alok-PORTEGE-R30-A:/mnt/tmp/alok# python /tmp/testlog.py 
2017-11-29 15:01:07,480 INFO: test 0
2017-11-29 15:01:07,480 INFO: test 1
2017-11-29 15:01:07,480 INFO: test 2
2017-11-29 15:01:07,480 INFO: test 3
2017-11-29 15:01:07,480 INFO: test 4
2017-11-29 15:01:07,480 INFO: test 0
2017-11-29 15:01:07,480 INFO: test 1
2017-11-29 15:01:07,480 INFO: test 2
2017-11-29 15:01:07,480 INFO: test 3
2017-11-29 15:01:07,480 INFO: test 4
```

what I expect is this should print only

```
root@alok-PORTEGE-R30-A:/mnt/tmp/alok# python /tmp/testlog.py 
2017-11-29 15:01:07,480 INFO: test 0
2017-11-29 15:01:07,480 INFO: test 1
2017-11-29 15:01:07,480 INFO: test 2
2017-11-29 15:01:07,480 INFO: test 3
2017-11-29 15:01:07,480 INFO: test 4
```

From where I am seeing extra flush on console?

Comment: how are you checking the logs? are you doing `tail -f` or just opening the log file once script executes?

Comment: I am using only that custom handler and printing log to console only. I am not using `FileHandler` so no point of `tail -f` to monitor logs

Answer (score 0):

After seeing others code I find it that I missed to empty `self.buffer` after flush. So proper code should be

```
from logging.handlers import BufferingHandler
import logging

LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s'
logger = logging.getLogger('LogArchiver')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter(LOG_FORMAT)

class MyLogHandler(BufferingHandler):
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        logging.handlers.BufferingHandler.__init__(self, capacity)

    def flush(self):
        for record in self.buffer:
            print(self.format(record))            
        super(MyLogHandler, self).flush()

    def shouldFlush(self, record):
        return False


h = MyLogHandler(1000)
h.setLevel(logging.INFO)
h.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(h)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(5):
        logger.info('test %s', i)
```

Comment: Yes, but you should (for thread-safe operation) use the parent class `flush()`: `super(MyLogHandler, self).flush()`

Comment: If I will use `super(MyLogHandler, self).flush()` then where how will I put my intended flushing strategy like sending email on flushing?

Comment: Just replace `self.buffer = []` with the `super(MyLogHandler, self).flush()`